# Find a sublist full of given item and replace it

Tags: python, list

Assume I have the list following

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

What I want to do is to compose all the same values following each other to strings. For instance

> [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,1,1]
>
> should be composed as the following
>
> ["1x7",2,3,"1x3","2x4","3x2",4,5,"1x2"]

I reckon multiplying each of the following values and checking if their product is different than 1,4,9,16,25 can work up to some point but when it comes to bigger lists, it won't be enough.

Is there a shortcut that python provides?

Comment: Is this a means to perform some kind of run-length encoding?

Comment: I am not familiar with what you mean, sorry. This data will be used for my arduino project but arduino has a little amount of memory. So i needed to compress it into some sort of form that requires less memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to collect consecutive runs of the same value.

```
from itertools import groupby
def condense(group):
    values = list(group)
    if len(values) > 1:
        return '{}x{}'.format(values[0], len(values))
    else:
        return values[0]
```

You can use this function in a list comprehensino

```
>>> data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
>>> [condense(g) for k,g in groupby(data)]
['1x4', 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, '2x2', 1, '2x2', '1x4', 3, '1x2', '2x2', 1, 2, '1x2', 3, '1x4', '2x2', 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, '1x2', 3, '1x7', 2, 1, 2, '1x8', 2, '1x4', '2x2', 3, '1x2', 2, 1, 3, 2, '1x2', 2, 1, '2x2', '1x13', 2, '1x3', '2x2', '1x2', '2x2', '1x3', '2x2', '1x4', 2, '1x3', 2, '1x2', 2, 1, 3, 2, '1x6', 2, '1x2', 3, '1x5', 3, '1x2', 3, '1x2', 2, '1x2', 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, '2x2', '1x4', 2, 3, '1x2', '2x6', 1, 2, '1x6', 2, 3, '1x2', 2, 1, 2, '1x2', 2, 3, '1x8', 4, '1x2', 2, 3, '1x2', 3, 2, '1x2', 2, 3, 1, '2x3', 1, '2x2', '1x3', 2, 3, '1x6', 4, 2, '1x3', 2, 1, '2x4', 1, 2, '1x2', '3x2', '1x2', 2, '1x3', '2x2', '1x2', 2, 3, '1x3', 4, '1x5', 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, '1x2', '2x2', 1, 4, 1, 2, '1x3', 3, '1x2', 3, 2, 1, '2x2', 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, '1x3', 3, 2, 1, 2, '1x2', '2x2', '1x10', '2x2', '1x3', '2x2', '1x2', 2, '1x2', 2, '1x3', 3, '1x3', 2, '1x2', 2, '1x2', 2, '1x2', 3, '1x2', 3, '1x2', 4, 1, 2, '1x2', '3x2', 4, '2x2', 5, '1x8', 3, 4, '1x6', 2, 1, 2, '1x2', 4, 3, '1x3', 3, '1x3', 2, 1, 3, 4, '2x3', '1x2', '2x2', '1x6', 2, 3, '1x2', 2, 3, '1x2', '2x2', '1x2', 2, '1x6', 2, '1x2', 4, '1x2', 3, 4, '1x20', '2x2', 1, '2x2', 1, 2, 1, '2x3', 1, '2x2', '1x3', 5, '1x2', 3, '1x7', '2x2', 3, 4, 2, '1x5', 3, '1x4', 3, '2x2', 1, 3, 4, 2, '1x2', 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, '1x5', 2, '1x3', 2, '1x5', 2, '1x3', 3, 2, '1x2', 4, '1x3', 2, '1x8', 2, 1, 3, '1x2', 3, '1x2', '2x2', '1x2', 2, '1x4', 2, '1x2', '2x2', '1x4', 2, 1, 2, '1x2', 2, '1x4', '2x2', 3, 1, 4, '1x2', 2, '1x6', 2, '1x2', 2, 5, '1x3', 2, '1x3', 2, 1, 4, 1, '3x2', '1x3', 3, '1x6', 2, 1, 2, '1x15', 2, '1x4', '2x2', '1x9', 2, '1x8', 2, '1x3', 2, '1x3', 2, 1, '2x2', 1, '2x2', '1x2', '2x2', 3, 1, 2, 1, '2x2', '1x4', 2, 4, '1x4', '2x2', '1x3', 2, '1x2', 2, '1x10', 2, '1x4', 2, 1, 3, 2, '1x11', 2, '1x5', 2, '1x2', '2x2', '1x3', 2, '1x2', 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, '1x2', 4, 2, '1x2', '3x2', '2x2', '1x3', 4, 3, 2, '1x10', 2, '1x3', '2x2', '1x2', '2x2', '1x6', '2x2', '1x2', 2, '1x2', 2, '1x2', 3, '1x3', 2, '1x3', '2x2', '1x2', 2, '1x2', 2, '1x2', 2, '1x2', 3, '1x2', 2, '1x2', '2x2', '1x4', '2x2', '1x3', 4, 1, 3, '2x2', '1x2', 3, 1, '2x2', 1, '2x2', 3, '1x16', '2x2', '1x7', 3, '1x5', 2, '1x5', 2, '1x5', '2x2', '1x4', 2, '1x2', 2, '1x2', 3, '1x3', 3, '1x4', '2x2', 4, 3, 4, 2, '1x5', '2x3', 3, '1x4', 2, '1x5', 2, '1x4', 2, '1x2', 2, 1, 2, 4, '1x4', '2x2', '1x2', 2, '1x4', 3, '1x3', 3, '1x4', 2, 1, '2x2', 3, 4, '1x2', '2x2', '1x8', 3, 2, '1x2', 3, '1x33', 2, '1x2', 2, '1x3', 2, 3, '1x5', 2, '1x6', 2, '1x5', 2, '1x2', 2, 1, '2x2', '1x5', 2, '1x2', 2, '1x8', 2, '1x3', '2x2', '1x2', 2, '1x9', 3, 2, '1x5', 2, '1x7', 3, '2x2', '1x5', 2, '1x3', 2, '1x10', 3, 1, 2, '1x3', '2x2', '1x2', 2, '1x2', 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, '1x2', 2, '1x6', 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want this data to take less space, you can use a dictionary with the items as keys and number of their appearance in the list as values.
I used `set` to remove duplicates and then created the dictionary.

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,1,1]
d = {i:a.count(i) for i in set(a)}
print(d)
```

output:

```
{1: 12, 2: 5, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 1}
```

Reading from and writing to a dictionary is a lot easier than a string in that form. You can also simply store a dictionary as `JSON` file.

**UPDATE**:

So if the sequence of the elements is important. You can do like this:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,1,1]
b = []
count = 1
for i in range(1,len(a)):
    if a[i-1] != a[i]:
        b.append((a[i-1],count))
        count = 0
    count += 1
b.append((a[-1],count))
print(b)
```

output:

```
[(1, 7), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 2), (4, 1), (5, 1), (1, 2)]
```

It will loop through the list and creates a tuple with the item as its first element and its counts as second element.

Comment: This will destroy the original sequence though. You'll know the counts of each value, but not the order they appeared

Comment: Ok. I didn't notice that the sequence was important. How about this new code?